# How to automate image screenshotting process in python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm working on a project that intends to develop a deep neural network that can detect birds in photographs. Firstly, I am supposed to collect data from a live youtube feed but I am still facing challenges with automating the process of taking screenshots from the livefeed. My code requires continuous manual rerun and I would like to have an automated function:

**Here is my code**

```
import  pyautogui, time
time.sleep(20)
screeshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screeshot.save('image2.png')
print('screenshot taken')
```

Comment: What's the problem with the existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem? Is it that you want it to keep taking screenshots while your ai is running? if so then just use `multiprocessing` or `threading`. or if you just want it to keep running use a loop.

Comment: Yes, I want a loop that can keep running while taking screenshots. But still facing challenges to come up with that loop.